# Outlook Add-in VSTO: Ribbon Type property is not shown

Tags: visual-studio, vsto, visual-studio-2005, outlook-addin

I am a new VSTO 2015 user. I want to add a custom group to the Outlook 2010 built-in Ribbon message tab. I followed a Microsoft example.

After creating the project I added a new Item and selected the Ribbon (Visual Designer). The ribbon shows up in the designer however I cannot see the RibbonType property in the Ribbon’s property window. Therefore I cannot select the Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Compose that will allow me to add the custom group to the message tab.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You need to set the RibbonType to Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer. This is not the default value, once you set this property you will be able to set the Ribbon Type property.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. My problem is that I cannot see at all the RibbonType property in the Ribbon’s property window. Therefore I cannot change the Ribbon Type.

Comment: Which outlook version do you have ?

Comment: I have Outlook 2010. I also tried to add a ribbon to Outlook 2013 and could not see the RibbonType property.

Comment: Open your ribbon designer file (Ribbon1.Designer.cs) and do the following: 1) Find private void InitializeComponent() method 2) Change below line:

this.RibbonType = "Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Read";
//into
this.RibbonType = "Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer";

Comment: Thank you Mostafa. Your answer helped me to resolve the problem. For the sake of the readers, I want to mention that the file name that was created was Ribbon1.vb which did not have the code that you mentioned that resides in theRibbon1.cs. However, for whatever reason the drop-down list of the Ribbon type start showing and I could select the Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Compose  property.

Thank you again. Menachem

Comment: Great to hear that! could you mark this as an answer. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To see the `RibbonType` property, you must select the correct part in the visual ribbon. Click on the top left part of the visual ribbon (showing the name of the Ribbon (just above "File") then you see the correct properties.