# Outlook VSTO - need help getting ribbon type property to display

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook, outlook-addin

I created an Outlook VSTO add in, added a custom ribbon.  The property "RibbonType" does not show up anywhere when I click on the "Ribbon1.cs".  I see the "(ApplicationSettings)" and under it I see "(PropertyBinding)" & "(Name)" - nothing else.

I followed another thread that says I have to add "this.RibbonType = "Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Read";" to the "Ribbon1.Designer.cs" file and I did.  It still does not show up.

```
    public Ribbon1()
        : base(Globals.Factory.GetRibbonFactory())
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        **this.RibbonType = "Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Read";**
    }
```

How do I make it show?

Comment: It seems like you are missing to derive your class from a base class. Can you add a link to the thread that you are following?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32682312/outlook-add-in-vsto-ribbon-type-property-is-not-shown.

Comment: I created it using "Add Item" --> "Ribbon (Visual Designer)".  I don't see how i can miss deriving it from the class.